# how to find whole squares between 2 numbers

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I want to find perfect square between two numbers A, B (numbers can be positive/negative). I also want to achieve time complexity of O(sqrt(abs(B))).

I wrote the following code for this :

```
count = (int)(Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.abs(B)) - Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(Math.abs(A))) + 1);
```

This normally works well but fails when the range is between -ve and +ve numbers.

For example is range is A = -1, B = 1. Then I think it should return 2 (0, 1) but returns 1.

I could not find the solution in other answers in SO. So, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why the C++ tag?

Comment: I am okay with solution for Java / C++ . I am more interested in logic

Comment: `floor(sqrt(abs(1)))` is 1, `ceil(sqrt(abs(-1)))`is 1, so if you subtract one from the other and add 1 you get ... 1. What's the problem here? Besides that, keep in mind that working with doubles could lead to precision issues and thus the cast to `int` could yield unexpected results.

Comment: What do you mean by a negative number being a perfect square? Are you wanting numbers that can be decomposed into `(a + ib) * (a - ib)`?

Comment: @Thomas .. I think the answer should be 2 and not 1.

Comment: @Bathsheba .. I meant that the range can be -ve , +ve

Comment: Care to explain why the answer should be 2? Your code implies 1 should be correct.

Comment: Please give me an example of what is your perception of the behaviour for negative numbers.

Comment: what if you have, say, `A = -2 and B = 1`? You'd get a negative number for `count`. You need to handle the case when either number is negative *separately*.

Comment: @Thomas . I think 0, 1 are two perfect squares in the range

Comment: @Bathsheba .. as I understand for -ve numbers, it should be invalid. But for 0, it should be perfect sqaure. Now, I tend to agree with "ControlAltDel" solution posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be no perfect squares (unless we consider numbers with `i` from -infinity to 0. So you could/should throw an IllegalArgumentException on negative start number, or just set the start to 0.

Comment: I agree. But I assume 0 as perfect square. So, it should be counted

Comment: @Sushil maybe my math isn't working today, but it looks like if you do what I suggest your count formula is going to calculate 1 - 0 + 1 = 2, which is what you want right?

Comment: I think you are correct on this. With this change, I will get correct counts

Answer (score 3):

Let us assume A, B ≥ 0.

Then A ≤ n² ≤ B is equivalent to √A ≤ n ≤ √B and to ceil(√A) ≤ n ≤ floor(√B).

Thus, the number of solutions is floor(√B) - ceil(√A) + 1.

If A < 0, replace A by 0. Then if B < A, there is no solution.

---

**Update by @Bathsheba**:

Finally, if you don't want 0 to be considered to be a perfect square then replace "If A < 0, replace A by 0" with "If A < 1, replace A by 1."

Comment: Is the superior answer. An analysis where A > 0 and B >= A would be the icing on the cake. (I'm from the 0 is not a perfect square brigade, unless you generalise to the complex plane).

Comment: @Bathsheba: if A < 1 replace A by 1.

Comment: Indeed; if that was in the answer then I'd upvote again if I could.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I am fulfilling the specifications given by the OP.

Comment: I couldn't resist. Roll back if you find my edit distasteful. Might be useful for future readers.